# ResourceBundle not found with Maven Shade plugin

Tags: java, resourcebundle, maven-shade-plugin

I have a java project that I want to put in a fat jar with the Shade plugin. I have created a resource bundle inside it. When I run the project with the IntelliJ "Run" everything works fine, however when I build the fat-jar and try to run that its says
 `java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name lang.lang, locale de`

The bundle is in that folder:

```
- src
  - main
    - resources
      - lang
        - lang_DE.properties
        - lang_EN.properties
```

Code that loads the bundle:

`ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang.lang", propertyService.getLanguage())` (which is working when running with intelliJ)

Shade Plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
        <outputFile>target\${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer">
          <basename>lang/lang</basename>
        </transformer>
      </transformers>
    </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also checked the JAR and the language files are where they should be, so they should be visible.
I added the second transformer, but I am not sure if this is neccessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finallly found it: It was the capital 'DE' and 'EN' in the filename, while a lower 'de' and 'en' where passed to the getBundle.
Renaming the files to

```
lang_de.properties
lang_en.properties
```

solved the problem.

I still have absolutely no idea why it worked when starting from IntelliJ and not when executing the fat JAR.

FYI: The ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer is NOT needed